# Format a table in R Markdown with a "footer" for each row

Tags: r, pdf, dplyr, r-markdown, flextable

My colleagues have requested, for reasons I cannot begin to try to explain or defend, a table format in which one of the columns is displayed as a footer, or a second row, after each row of data, merged across the width of the rest of the columns. I need to be able to print this table to a PDF using R Markdown.

If I create a dummy dataframe:

```
dummy <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"),
                    Color = c("Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Red"),
                    Shape = c("Triangle", "Square", "Circle", "Square"),
                    Note = c("Test Comment One", "Another Test Comment", "", "Even More Test Comments"))
```

I'd like to format it such that the Note column is displayed as a separate row beneath each row of categorical data like:

[image]

I'm using flextable for other things so I suppose I'd like to use it here, but it can be limiting, so I'm open to other solutions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try the gt package. You can easily create footnotes with it. The workflow is similar to ggplot and the tables look great!

https://gt.rstudio.com/

Comment: What are the arguments? Can you share a code that shows evidence it's working like ggplot2, can you share a code that shows how to do it?